# SQL Find pairs of data in rows and convert to columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to setup a query to pull employee tenure reports. I have an employee status table that tracks information for each employee (e.g. -Hire Date, Term Date, Salary Change, etc.) The table looks like this:

```
EmployeeID    |   Date   |   Event
      1       |  1/1/99  |      1
      2       |  1/2/99  |      1
      1       |  1/3/99  |      2
      1       |  1/4/99  |      1
```

I used a pivot table to move the table from a vertical layout to a horizontal layout

```
SELECT        [FK_EmployeeID], MAX([1]) AS [Hire Date], ISNULL(MAX([2]), DATEADD(d, 1, GETDATE())) AS [Term Date]
FROM            DT_EmployeeStatusEvents PIVOT (MAX([Date]) FOR [EventType] IN ([1], [2])) T
GROUP BY [FK_EmployeeID]
```

I get a result like this:

```
EmployeeID    |   1      |   2
      1       |  1/4/99  | 1/3/99
      2       |  1/2/99  |  *null*
```

However, the problem I run into is that I need both sets of values for each employee. (We hire a lot of recurring seasonals) What I would like is a way to convert the columns to rows selecting the hire date (1) and the very next term date (2) for each employee like this:

```
EmployeeID    |   1      |   2
      1       |  1/1/99  | 1/3/99
      2       |  1/2/99  |  *null*
      1       |  1/4/99  |  *null*
```

Is this possible? I've looked at a lot of the PIVOT examples and they all show an aggregate function.

Comment: Is it just those 2 events or more than that?

Comment: There are a lot more events, but I am only needing the 1 (Hire Date) and 2 (Term Date) events. Some of our seasonals have been hired on for multiple seasons. Example -IF someone was hired for Spring, Summer, and Fall in 2011, 2012, and 2013 would have 3 pairs of data. (e.g. -3 hire dates, and 3 associated term dates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to pivot a `datetime` value so you are limited to using either `max` or `min` as the aggregate function.  When you use those you will only return one row for each `employeeid`.

In order to get past this you will need to have some value that will be used during the grouping of your data - I would suggest using a windowing function like `row_number()`. You can make your subquery:

```
select employeeid, date, event
  , row_number() over(partition by employeeid, event
                      order by date) seq
from DT_EmployeeStatusEvents
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6e40/4). This creates a unique value for each `employeeId` and `event` combination.  This new number will then be grouped on so you can return multiple rows.  You full query will be:

```
select employeeid, [1], [2]
from 
(
  select employeeid, date, event
    , row_number() over(partition by employeeid, event
                        order by date) seq
  from DT_EmployeeStatusEvents
) d
pivot
(
  max(date)
  for event in ([1], [2])
) piv
order by employeeid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6e40/5)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started...

```
DECLARE @EMP TABLE (EMPID INT, dDATE DATETIME, EVENTTYPE INT)
INSERT INTO @EMP
SELECT 1,'1/1/99',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'1/2/99',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'1/3/99',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'1/4/99',1

SELECT EMPID, HIRE, TERM
FROM (SELECT EMPID, dDATE, 'HIRE' AS X, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPID, EVENTTYPE ORDER BY DDATE) AS INSTANCE FROM @EMP WHERE EVENTTYPE=1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT EMPID, dDATE, 'TERM' AS X, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPID, EVENTTYPE ORDER BY DDATE) AS INSTANCE FROM @EMP WHERE EVENTTYPE=2) DATATABLE
PIVOT (MIN([DDATE])
       FOR X IN ([HIRE],[TERM])) PIVOTTABLE
```